# How to refine the use of stepVeriifer in this test?

Tags: project-reactor

I am using Flux from Reactor (projectreactor.io) to create a reactive stream.

In my stream generation method (`connect()`), I will put out in a number of message of type X, then at last near the end of the operation, I will emit a message of type Y and then call `complete()` of the flux stream.

The number of message X is unknown at the time of test. It could be more or less depending on the duration the test is run.

Here is my test condition at the moment:

```
var connectStream = service.connect();
StepVerifier.create(connectStream)
  .recordWith(ArrayList::new)
  .thenConsumeWhile(x -> true)
  .verifyComplete();
```

It allows me to test the stream is closed by the server side.

My question is more of 'How to do it' nature: How can I ensure that there are more than 1 message of X and they are all followed a single message Y?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you want "one or more" messages of type `X`, then exactly one of type `Y`:

```
StepVerifier.create(new Main().getFlux())
        .expectNextMatches(x -> x.equals("X"))
        .thenConsumeWhile(x -> x.equals("X"))
        .expectNextMatches(x -> x.equals("Y"))
        .verifyComplete();
```

So:

```
Flux.just("X", "X", "X", "Y"); //Passes
Flux.just("X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y"); //Fails
Flux.just("Y"); //Fails
```

In this trivial example you could of course just use `expectNext()` in place of `expectNextMatches()` - I use the latter as you say you want to test for *types* rather than values, so I suspect it's likely you'll need that predicate rather than a fixed value.